# My mapbox markers not displaying

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I've been working with a Mapbox map for some time now, and I initialize it like this:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = "token"; //My token
this.map = L.mapbox.map("elmoMap", "mapid", {
    attributionControl: false,
    infoControl: true,
    maxZoom: 12,
    minZo0m: 5
}).setView(new L.LatLng(64.272275900963, 10.036372782080434), 8);

this.map.on('layeradd', function(e: any) {
    if (e.layer && e.layer.feature && e.layer.feature.properties && e.layer.feature.properties.icon) {
        var marker = e.layer;
        var feature: Models.IFeature = marker.feature;
        var icon = feature.properties.icon;
        marker.setIcon(L.icon(icon));
    }
});
```

I added a layer with a image icon:

```
var structuresData = {
    type: "Feature",
    geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [10.02, 64.2]
    },
    properties: {
        title: "Buoy",
        mapLayer: "Structures",
        icon: {
            iconUrl: "/img/32_573586.png",
            iconSize: [32, 32], // size of the icon
            iconAnchor: [16, 16], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            popupAnchor: [0, -16], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            className: "dot"
        }
    }
}

var structuresLayer = L.geoJson(structuresData);
this.map.addLayer(structuresLayer);
```

This used to work, but suddenly the marker and the layer stopped showing up. All i get in my console is:

```
GET http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.0/images/marker-icon.png 404 (Not Found)
```

But I'm not sure if it is related at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging by the elimination method, I finally found the source of the problem. It was in the css, in an external theme.

The culprit was this line:

```
img {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

I removed it and the markers came back :)

Comment: This sure saved me a headache and a half. The same thing happened to me.